# Is there a definition that captures the number of disjoint continuous curves in a graph?

Tags: definition, curves

The graph of $f(x) = x$ has one such curve, the graph of $f(x) = 1/x$ has two such curves, the graph of $x^{2}y^{2}-x^{2}-y^{2}=0$ has four such curves, and the graph of $f(x) = \tan x$ has infinite such curves.

Is there a definition of such a number, given an arbitrary curve? I'd like to find this definition to see if there is a way to compute this number given an arbitrary equation.

Comment: I mean, technically $f(x)=x$ has infinitely many. Just partition the graph into sections: $f(x)=\bigcup_{z\in \mathbb{Z}}f_z(x)$, where $f_z=f|_{[z, 1+z)}$. These are clearly disjoint and continuous. I think you are referring to something that relates to the number of asymptotes of a graph.

Comment: It seems that the concept you are looking for is (path-)connected components.

Comment: thanks for the answers